# Multiple input files awk command line

Tags: awk

I am an awk newbie and admittedly don't understand how the FNR NR drives looping through files. I'm able to get two input files working. I need to add another (inputFile3).

I am running this from the command line:

```
awk -f parseField.awk inputFile1.csv inputFile2.csv ./inputFile3.TXT
```

Currently, I loop through inputFile3 using:

```
FNR!=NR {...}
```

I loop through inputFile1 using:

```
FNR==NR {...}
```

I need to add another file to the mix (inputFile2). What is the syntax that I can use in my awk script (parseField) to access that third input file?

Comment: `FNR` == "The input record number in the current input file." `NR` == "The total number of input records seen so far." so `FNR==NR` for the first file and is different for every other file. What are you trying to do with your third file?

Answer (score 4):

To add to @EtanReisner 's good information, you can keep a counter: `FNR==1 {file_number++}`. This will increase the counter whenever the first line of a file is read.

All together, you can say:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print "start program"}
NR==1 {print "reading first file"}
FNR==1 {filenum++; print "I am in file number", filenum}
{ ... }
```

If you are in a <strike>GNU</strike> [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) ([thanks Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202938/multiple-input-files-awk-command-line/33203170?noredirect=1#comment54212021_33203170)) you can also use the `FILENAME` variable. Or also the `ARGC` variables and `ARGV` array.

---

Also see information about this in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/):

> Another construct that is often used in awk is as follows:
>
> ```
> $ awk 'NR == FNR { # some actions; next} # other condition {# other actions}' file1.txt file2.txt
> ```
>
> This is used when processing two files. When processing more than one
>   file, awk reads each file sequentially, one after another, in the
>   order they are specified on the command line. The special variable NR
>   stores the total number of input records read so far, regardless of
>   how many files have been read. The value of NR starts at 1 and always
>   increases until the program terminates. Another variable, FNR, stores
>   the number of records read from the current file being processed. The
>   value of FNR starts at 1, increases until the end of the current file
>   is reached, then is set again to 1 as soon as the first line of the
>   next file is read, and so on. So, the condition NR == FNR is only true
>   while awk is reading the first file.

Comment: FILENAME is part of POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  So too is the ARGV array, and ARGC variable — the indexes of ARGV start from 0 (rather than 1), and the arguments recorded exclude the options to `awk` and the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, so that's why I suggest using a counter whenever `FNR==1` as the most reliable way to do this.

Comment: I agree that `FNR == 1` is a good way of detecting a change of file.  Your comment about GNU Awk is more restrictive than need be (`FILENAME` is not exclusively in GNU Awk).  And knowing that ARGC and ARGV exist can be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah, now I see your point. Thanks for it, updated!

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as the POSIX FILENAME solution, but handy for dusty, old `awk`s that lack too many features. You can make a compound statement that manipulates your data before sending it to `awk` in a couple of ways...

**Option 1**

First, you could output the filenumber on its own before each file that you send to `awk`. So, if your files look like this:

**file1**

```
Line 1 of 1
```

**file2**

```
Line 1 of 2
Line 2 of 2
```

**file3**

```
Line 1 of 3
Line 2 of 3
Line 3 of 3
```

You could do this:

```
{ echo 1; cat file1; echo 2; cat file2; echo 3; cat file3; }
1
Line 1 of 1
2
Line 1 of 2
Line 2 of 2
3
Line 1 of 3
Line 2 of 3
Line 3 of 3
```

and pipe that into `awk` and then pick up the filenumber every time the number of fields is 1

```
{ echo 1; cat file1; echo 2; cat file2; echo 3; cat file3; } | awk 'NF==1{file=$1;next} {print file,$0}'
1 Line 1 of 1
2 Line 1 of 2
2 Line 2 of 2
3 Line 1 of 3
3 Line 2 of 3
3 Line 3 of 3
```

**Option 2**

Or, you could edit the filenumber onto the start, or end, of every line so it is available as `$1` inside `awk`, like this:

```
{ sed 's/^/1 /' file1; sed 's/^/2 /' file2; sed 's/^/3 /' file3; }
1 Line 1 of 1
2 Line 1 of 2
2 Line 2 of 2
3 Line 1 of 3
3 Line 2 of 3
3 Line 3 of 3
```

So, now you can do

```
{ sed 's/^/1 /' file1; sed 's/^/2 /' file2; sed 's/^/3 /' file3; } | awk '{file=$1; ...}'
```

I'm still voting for @fedorqui's solution though :-)